# Play Framework 2 template Form None.get

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

Im new to Play 2 and Scala, and im getting a strange Exception in my template:

```
Execution exception
-------------------

[NoSuchElementException: None.get]
In /home/nic/workspaces/scala-ide/scims/app/views/persons/detailTabs/personal.scala.html at line 4.

1. @(personId: Long, personDetailTabForm: Form[dto.PersonDetailTab])(implicit formOptions: dto.PersonFormOptions)
2. @implicitFieldConstructor = @{ helper.FieldConstructor(support.bs3HorizField.f) }
3. 
4. @persons.detail("personal", personDetailTabForm.get.firstName) {
```

The personDetailTabForm is an empty form object defined as:

```
  val personalDetailTabForm: Form[PersonDetailTab] = Form(
    mapping(
      "firstName"     -> text.verifying(nonEmpty),
      "middleName"    -> text,
      "lastName"      -> text.verifying(nonEmpty),
      "gender"        -> text,
      "dateOfBirth"   -> jodaDate("yyyy-MM-dd"),
      "ethnicity"     -> text,
      "maritalStatus" -> text,
      "password"      -> text
    )(PersonDetailTab.apply)(PersonDetailTab.unapply)
  )
```

Any ideas as to what's wrong here?

I was under the impression a variable would have to be an Option to get a None?

Cheers
NFV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `get` on `personDetailTabForm` - Looking up it's ScalaDoc: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form - it seems that `.get` returns the `PersonDetailTab` value that the form holds - IF, as the docs say, '*the submission was a success*'.

You're seeing the `None.get` exception because most likely `play.api.data.Form[T]` simply uses `Option[T]` and `get` returns `Some[T]` when the form holds a valid value and `None` otherwise.

So on your line 4, in the scala template, you have something like

```
personDetailTabForm.get.firstName
```

That's a `String`, but you can expect a value only when the form's underlying `PersonDetailTab` itself has a value.  I am not sure what you want to do, but you're dealing with a case where a value you want to render in a template might not be there, for whatever reason. In which case:

```
@personDetailTabForm.value.map{ personDetailTab => 
  @persons.detail("personal", personDetailTab.firstName) // { ... whatever else
  // anything else you want to render
} getOrElse { // errors in the form; personDetailTabForm cannot yield a valid personDetailTab
  <h3> oops, what went wrong here? </h2>

}
```

It all depends on what you want to do in `personal.scala.html`. `Form[T]` is a good way
to deal with input and validation of some `T` thing, but if you are just displaying it, 
and if you have a `T` (in your case `PersonDetailTab`) just pass that to the template as it is. If your `PersonDetailTab` may or may not exist, then just use `Option[PersonDetailTab]` instead `Form[PersonDetailTab]`.